# Word to express that you have done something so many times, it becomes boring/unenjoyable

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term/words to describe that you lost intrest in doing something because you have repeated it so many times? Examples for these scenarios:

- You liked hamburgers a lot, but because you have eaten them throughout the years so many times, you dislike them now
- That song you once listened to the first time sounded really good, but after listening to it for many hours, it becomes a pain in the ears or just a boring song

Comment: I use the verb _saturate_ for this, and it sounds natural to my ear, but that sense isn't listed in any dictionary and may be limited to my family. (_"It's saturated for me now, I've seen it too many times"_)

Answer (score 2):

The word **jaded**, with the second meaning of "*Dulled by surfeit; sated*" on [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/jaded), may have the meaning you want.

Answer (score 1):

To be satisfied to the point of disinterest = to be "**sated**".

> *sate* [verb] [transitive]
>
> 1: to cloy with overabundance: glut
>
> 2: to appease by indulging to the full
>
> - *sate one's thirst*
>
> *Sate* (and *satiate*) may sometimes imply only complete satisfaction but more often suggest repletion that has destroyed interest or desire
> [... as reflected in the above ordering of senses].
>
> - *years of globe-trotting had satiated their interest in travel*
> - *readers were sated with sensationalistic stories*

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sate)]

Comment: Is the apparent quote actually given at the TFD reference?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I fixed the link. Thanks

Comment: I still can't find 'They were "sated" by too much of a good thing. The very thought of more turned them away.' But you seem to give the sentence as a bona fide rather than homespun example. / There are other dictionaries giving the relevant sense.

Comment: Sorry if something is confusing for you. The example is a bit labored. I was thinking about the quail  (in the Bible) as an example of being "sated" by the very food the Israelites requested... I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm concerned about possible misrepresentation. Showing 'They were "sated" by too much of a good thing. The very thought of more turned them away.' in a block quote followed by a linked reference indicates it's a genuine quote, adding support. But _is_ it? / Other dictionaries clearly include the 'over' in 'over-fill'; the usage note at [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sate) is spot on.

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that. Feel free to edit my answer for better form.

Comment: Thank you so much, Edwin. I AM sorry that I left such a "bare bones" answer before, but I think of SE in terms of actually "answering questions" primarily (and genuinely competitively) - and not usually in terms of form or style. In other words, I think SE should focus more on offering "accurate and helpful" information/answers to questions. However, your stylish revisions are excellent...

Comment: The stated aim of ELU is to use questions as platforms on which to build widely accessible information about how the English language is actually used. It might sound a little rude, but answering questions is not the primary aim. Some are closed because it's highly unlikely anyone else will benefit from such narrowly scoped personal queries.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - That may be true, and probably is true in your view, however, it is very unfriendly to users who come here for answers as well as for potential contributors that attempt to leave alternative answers. My observation has been that SE is frequently rude and closed to any criticism. I suspect that was not the original intent.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - And, the (overly) competitive, "gaming" envirionment, is another thing altogether... It is - IMO - insufferable.

Comment: It's not meant to be a competition (other than to give the best information / analyses one can find). The rep-thing is a useful filter and to some extent comment on accuracy. And if A 'beats' B to a similar answer, it often means the questioner was in the same time zone as A. / Obviously, clear, genuine and on-topic questions will be given an answer in the thread or elsewhere on the site.

Comment: I agree - the "gaming" aspect that I was making referriences to was mainly in the past. That does seem less prevalent now. But, honestly, When I come here to ask a question, it is always a genuine question. So, I take the good with the bad.

Answer (score 0):

When you stop feeling a sensation after repeated exposure, you have been *inured*, (which can carry a negative connotation, like inured against the world’s suffering), or developed *tolerance* for that thing (in the language of addiction).

When you no longer feel pleasure doing the same thing, in psychology, they call that *hedonic adaptation*, meaning, pleasure is sometimes like a finite currency which gets spent and then exhausted (for food, sex, and so on). The chronic condition of no longer feeling any pleasure is called *anhedonia*.

Doing the same thing too many times in a short period might cause it to become displeasurable, because you have exceeded past *homeostasis*, or, the organisms’s need to maintain equilibria of various sorts, such as hunger, temperature, energy, salt levels, and so on.

In common language, you can say “you’ve had enough”, you’re “full”, “done”, or just that you “don’t want anymore”.

I can brainstorm more ways to express this, like that “your will has been appetized.”

Walt Whitman greatly said about school, “I liked it so much, I didn’t feel any need to go on,” implying that he dropped out, not because he didn’t like it (more likely), but tongue-in-cheekily, claiming that it was he liked it so much, he was contented.

In Swedish, the word *lagom* means “just right” - we can compare that to something which is not “just right”, but has been stuffed, or is engorged, like geese which are force fed with tubes to fatten their livers, making foie gras. Shakespeare wrote, “this overflows the measure” (the measuring cup), to mean, “this is excessive, beyond the point of indulgence.”

And there are many ways and directions I could go on. I think *ennui*, or boredom, comes close to what you describe - the casual, vacant feeling of “same-old”, “day-in, day-out”.

But as a speaker of English, I’m not sure we have a set phrase we truly use, but get by with circumlocution, since it’s such a well-known concept - many times I have heard people say, “I listened to it so many times I can’t listen to it anymore.” That really is the most natural way to say it.

Answer (score 0):

Though the root meaning of **overexposed** is simply 'given, or subjected to too much exposure [to something or someone]', there are also broadened usages – but one has to venture further than the more respected online dictionaries for the general 'turned off as a result of of overexposure' sense:

> *Overexposed*:
>
> Something that has been played, listened to, or talked about so much
> to the point where the object becomes unbearable and the general
> public begins to build a collective hatred for the poor thing. This
> usually happens to really good YouTube videos, Vines, or songs that go
> viral; however this can happen to many other things ranging from memes
> to people.

[[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Overexposed)]

[[Oxford Languages Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=overexposure+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=overexposure+meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l6j0i22i30l3.1448132229j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) comes close to defining this broader sense of the noun:

> *Overexposure*: excessive media coverage, especially to the point that people lose interest.
>
> - *at certain times, a celebrity may suffer from overexposure*

- *Just a case of overexposure, I'd say.*

Answer (score 0):

You could say that you are **sick of** the food or song in question. [MW defines this as](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sick) "having a strong distaste from surfeit: satiated."

(Often this is used to express frustration with some repeated annoyance, as in "I'm sick of you complaining," but I've also heard it used in the context you describe.)